# lime.fill.Frame isn't a constructor

Tags: javascript, sprite-sheet

I'm trying to write a JS script using Lime.js to make an animation walk across the screen.  The source for the image is a spritesheet.  When is gets to this

var frame = new lime.fill.Frame('image.png', 40, 50, 100, 100);

the debugger says that lime.fill.Frame isn't a constructor.  Can anyone help me out with this?  I don't understand how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: The message probably means that the file that defines `lime.fill.Frame` was not loaded. Post the HTML you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the second parameter isn't the "goog.math.Rect" type.
lime.fill.Frame(img, rect, opt_offset, opt_size, opt_rotated)
Image fill.
Parameters:
{string|Image|lime.Sprite} img
Image.
**{goog.math.Rect} rect**
Crop frame.
opt_offset
opt_size
opt_rotated